# Executing a script at an exact time in future

Tags: php, background, cron, message-queue, future

I work on a PHP project where users place advertising posts. When advertising post is placed online it is given a "hide date" (stored in database), when it will no longer be shown to the users. When "hide date" (e.g. next Monday at 10:00am) occurres I need to fire a script that makes changes in the database (not related to hiding the ad).

**Question:**
How do I run a script at the exact time in future(at "hide date").

I google'd a lot and didn't find any good solution.

**Found possible solutions:**

- Cron isn't considered any more because of its lack of accuracy (for my task even seconds matter).
- Write a daemon which will check every second if there is a record with a "hide date" but it can be very consuming.
- Another way as I was told that message queues could be of help, but after reading some of the documentation I didn't find a way of setting date and time of processing the message in queue.

Can anyone point out where to look? Any tool/language is considered.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that ads show until a week after
Create a field in your ads table called expiry_date (timestamp)
When a new ad is inserted, do the following

```
$expiry_date = strtotime("+ 7 days");
```

Then insert the expiry date along with the record
Next, in the page that displays the ads, select only ads whose expiry date did not pass yet, so

```
SELECT * FROM ads WHERE expiry_date >= NOW()
```

This will only show ads that didn't expire yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have problem with hiding the advertising posts. I need to run script  at the exact time to make changes in database not related to hiding ads.

Answer (score 0):

If your site is running on a linux server, you can add a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to trigger your update script.

If your site is running Windows, use [Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task) instead.

However, it doesn't really sound like your best solution. You could store the "hide date" in the database along with the rest of the post's data. Then you can simply filter the posts in your display code.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My server runs linux and the cron would be the right choice but cron has a problem with executing at a precise time (in my task even seconds matter). Also "hide date" is stored in database. I'll edit update my post with this data.